# キーボード入力でフレームを移動させる

Tags: java, swing

キーボードの矢印を押したときに、表示したフレームがその方向に１０移動するプログラムを作成しています。キーボードの入力は検知しているのですが、フレームが動きません。どうやったら動きますでしょうか。以下作成したプログラム。

```
//インポート・ファイル
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

//メイン・クラス

public class framemoving
{

    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

 //メイン・メソッド
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  framemoving test = new framemoving();
 }
 //コンストラクタ
 public framemoving()
 {

 //基礎フレームの設定。
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setSize(250,250);
 frame.setLocation(x, y);
 frame.setTitle("Key_test");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setVisible(true);

 //キーボード・リスナーの設定
//フレームにキーボード入力の受信を登録
  frame.addKeyListener(new Keyboard_input());

 }

//キーボードのためのクラス

class Keyboard_input implements KeyListener
{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("keyPressed.");

        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP : y = y - 10; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT : x=x+10; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN : y=y+10; break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT : x=x-10;  break;
    }
}
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
 {
  //keyReleasedに対するメッセージを表示
  System.out.println("keyReleased.");
}
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
 {
  //keyTypedに対するメッセージを表示
  System.out.println("keyTyped.");
 }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

フレーム(`JFrame`オブジェクト)の [`setLocation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setLocation(int,int))メソッドを再度呼んで位置を更新してあげれば良いと思います。

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("keyPressed.");

    // 現在の位置
    Point point = frame.getLocation();
    int x = point.x;
    int y = point.y;
    switch(e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP : y = y - 10; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT : x=x+10; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN : y=y+10; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT : x=x-10;  break;
    }
    frame.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

[コード差分](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/commit/8dbec7d38ad3eaed63a8e4d6680e3790e1273455)